# Android convert DateTime from AM/PM to 24 hours

Tags: android, datetime

After research on SO, I found this code, but it doesnt work for me. Gives a error and I can´t figure out why. I already tried to change the format, and nothing.

```
String date = "11/28/2012 10:05:00 AM";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
Date testDate = null;

try {
    testDate = sdf.parse(date);
} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What error?  "Give a error"?

Comment: Hi Simon. Thank you for your reply. the Variable testDate returns the value null.

Comment: http://ideone.com/Slil2i I compile this code and its working fine for me.

Comment: Saifuddin, you got a result for the variable testDate ? I compile again, and still give me null on the variable. Better close eclipse and open it again.

Comment: Open eclipse again, clean, build, and still give null on testDate variable. Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: You said that you get an error.  What error and where?

Comment: The error, is that the testDate variable returns the value null.

Comment: Just copy and pasted it, works for me too.  Try deleting your imports and re importing(cmd-shift-o) and see if maybe you imported the wrong date class or something.  Or else try stepping through it to see if your doing something weird

Comment: It might seem pedantic, but it's important to understand that parse returning null is not an error.   It will return null if it can't parse the date string you supply with format mask.

Comment: Simon, but if the parse is returning null, is because something is wrong or not ? or i just can parse some date strings formats ? Sorry about my questions. And my bad english. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this and it will work :

```
{ 
    testDate = sdf.parse(date.toString());
}
```